# The operand for the method is not an element ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am getting below error when I compile.

Operand for the method is not an element  for code

DataSourceName dataSourceName = queryDataSourceStr(DMF***TargetEntity, **DMF****PostalAddressView**);

Error Line is appearing under "DMF****PostalAddressView".

Confused with the error appearing at this place. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't very clear, but it has something to do with your environment.

`queryDataSourceStr` accepts two parameters like this:

`queryDataSourceStr(queryName, dataSourceName)`

So for your line

> `queryDataSourceStr(DMF***TargetEntity, DMF****PostalAddressView);`

Go to the `AOT>\Queries\DMF***TargetEntity` and look for the DataSource `DMF****PostalAddressView` and see if it exists.

See if you've customized that query, if config keys are on/off, or if you are missing model files. `DMF` objects are apart of the data migration framework.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. I searched in the Queries\DMF**TargetEntity for DMF**PostalAddressView. The datasource name has "_1" at the end. I removed that  "_1" and it worked. Thanks. @Alex Kwitny